# Using IsBlank in formula for Date Time Picker field on Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, date-time, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

Pretty new to SharePoint and Power Apps so would like to ask if what I am trying to do is feasible.

I have a Date Time Picker field in my formula in Power Apps and currently, its default value is set to:
`Now()`

I would like to know if it is possible to check first if the value for that column in the list item is empty or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for blank values in Power Apps using `IsBlank()` or `IsBlankOrError()` functions.

**For example**:

Check if selected date in date picker control in Power Apps is blank or not:

```
IsBlank(DatePicker1.SelectedDate)
```

OR

```
IsBlankOrError(DatePicker1.SelectedDate)
```

Check if date column value in current SharePoint form context is blank or not:

```
IsBlank(ThisItem.NameOfDateColumn)
```

OR

```
IsBlankOrError(ThisItem.NameOfDateColumn)
```

Where `NameOfDateColumn` is the name of your date & time column in SharePoint list.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. I used the IsBlank property like how you suggested.